# Executing a Python script from the command line in Windows 7

Tags: python

I seem to be having a problem with executing a Python script from a <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> terminal.

I completed the following steps:

1. Used the shebang line before typing my script for all .py files. An example of what I did below for a script called `Primefactorization.py`.

   ```
   #! python3
   ```
2. I created a batch file in the same folder with the same name and input the following code:

   ```
   @python.exe C:\Python Scripts\Primefactorization.py %*
   ```
3. I added the path (`C:\Python Scripts`) to the `PATH` variable in the environment variables window.
4. When I try to invoke the script using the Run command in Windows 7, the shell opens and immediately disappears.
5. Based on a past answer to a similar problem on Stack Overflow, I also added the following code prompting the user for input before exiting. But that doesn't seem to work.

   ```
   x = input('press enter to close')
   ```

Could you please let me know where the problem might be?

Comment: If you open a command prompt, and then type `python` there, do you get a python prompt? If yes, if you type `python yourscript.py` at a command prompt, is your script executed?

Comment: Is your script running without errors? Errors from a Python script will immediately close command line windows if not explicitly caught.

Comment: If i type python in my command prompt. It does open the python console.

however , 'python pythonscript.py' doesnt work. i get the following error 'Cant open file myscript.py: [Errno2] no such file or directory.' Even though the script is in the same directory as the python exe file.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - yes the script runs fine when i run it from IDLE

Comment: Perhaps your environment variables are off in the command prompt. In the command line, open Python and then check what the directory is by typing in `import os` and then `print os.getcwd()` to print the directory the python executable is in and see if it matches the path you expect.

Comment: os.getcwd() points to C:/Python34 where all the scripts are stored.

the script seems to run after chaging my directory path to C:/Python34.

C:\Python34 python myscript.py seems to executing. But i'm still having trouble running the script directly from win+r

Comment: Run the batch file from the command line instead of Win+R. Then the console won't disappear immediately and you'll be able to see what the error is.

Comment: i tried running the bat file directly from the command prompt. I get the following error

**python.exe :  can't open file 'C:\Python': [Errno2]**

it should be C:\Python34 right? how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path has a space in it.  Enclose it in double quotes. For example:

```
python.exe "C:\Python Scripts\Primefactorization.py"
```

Comment: this is in the batch file? should i skip the %*

Comment: Yes, in the batch file. You can skip the `%*`, as I assume your program doesnt require any arguments. Obviously, also make sure that `C:\Python Scripts\Primefactorization.py` exists.

Comment: Thanks .. this finally seems to be a workaround :). Any idea why this works?

Comment: Your path had a space in it. Without quotes, you were telling `python.exe` to run  run the file `C:\Python` with the argument `Scripts\Primefactorization.py`